# Why Python shuffle list member on class constructor

Tags: python

I have a list that contains student names `student_names = []`. This list get it's names from a method called `get_student_names(data)`. If I passed `student_names` into a class constructor, the list member will be shuffled by itself

`di = DifficultyIndex(student_names, .., .., .., ..)`

I should called `get_student_names()` to get unshuffled list member

`di = DifficultyIndex(get_student_names(data), .., .., .., ..)`

How is this happen? What the exaplanation for this kind of event?

This is the code:

```
class DifficultyIndex():
　　def __init__(self, answered_questions, student_names, high_group, low_group):
    　　self.answered_questions = answered_questions
    　　self.student_names = student_names
    　　self.high_group = high_group
    　　self.low_group = low_group
        print(answered_questions)
    .
    .
    .

def get_student_names(data):
    student_names = []

    for index, line in enumerate(data):
        if index is not 0: 
            temp = line.split(',')
            student_names.append(temp[0])
    return student_names

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_args()
    data = args.file.readlines()
    .
    .
    .
    student_names = get_student_names(data)
    # This code works
    di = DifficultyIndex(answered_question, get_student_names(data), high_group[0], low_group[0])
    # This code didn't works
    # di = DifficultyIndex(answered_question, student_names, high_group[0], low_group[0])
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by shuffled?

Comment: @Rodolfo I have added code example

Comment: @PaulRooney elements position in the list is changed

Comment: Whatever is doing the shuffling has to be in one of the `...` sections of your code. We can't guess what is going on without seeing it.

Comment: @Blckknght I wrote `...` because they've no interaction with the list I'm trying to passed to the class.

Comment: If you want us to help, you need to provide code that will let us reproduce the issue. If I run the code you've shown, I don't get the issue you describe (I get other errors since there's no `get_args` function, and even if I fixed that, I wouldn't get things out of order). In simplifying your code to show us, you've cut out whatever is causing the problem. As Rodolfo commented a while ago, please give a [mcve]. In figuring out what to put in an example that can reproduce the issue, there's a decent chance you'll find the error yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Behind lists, in Python, are pointers. Basically, this means that if you pass a list to some method, it might mess up with it. Sometimes, you actually want the method to change your list (`remove`, `append`...), but sometimes you only want the method to process the data contained in your list.

To prevent such side-effects, pass a copy of your list to the method, instead of your list itself. This is done with calling `that_function(list(myList))` instead of `that_function(myList)`. Note that

```
copy = myList
that_function(copy)
```

will **not** work, because in this case, `copy` is actually the same pointer as `myList`. You need to call the copy constructor, `list()`.

Comment: I tried to pass the list with `list(my_list)` but the result is the same. List member still shuffled.